# What do you call a word with affixes?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, affixes

Is it an affixed word? Affixated word? Affixation results in a ______?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you come back online, could you please clarify your question? It seems you are looking for an adjective for "a word that has an affix" Or are you looking for a word that means a term that has two or more affixes? e.g. "**[un] + [dis] + clos(e) + [ed]**" (undisclosed) In the meantime I am casting my vote to put the question on hold  for being unclear. P.S it also lacks any effort of research.

Answer (score 1):

It is a **derivative word**.

From the Merriam-Webster definition of the noun [*affix*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affix):

> **1** *grammar* : one or more sounds or letters occurring as a bound form attached to the beginning or end of a word, base, or phrase or inserted within a word or base and serving to produce a derivative word or an inflectional form • The *affix* in the word "attendance" is "-ance."

And from Merriam-Webster's definition of the noun [*derivative*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/derivative):

> **1** *linguistics* : a word formed from another word or base : a word formed by derivation • "pointy," "pointed," and other *derivatives* of "point"

Comment: Derivational affixes are only one kind of affix. There are also [inflectional affixes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf).